# A word or expression that means somebody's name is not "real"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions, expression-choice

I'm interviewing someone and he doesn't want his real name showing up, so how could I rephrase the following sentence?

> We hide his real name under the name Luke.

Answer (score 2):

Typically in an article, you would see it phrased as:

> Luke (not his real name) told us that...

or

> The interviewee, designated here as Luke, said...

Khaled's answers are also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when someone uses a different name from his real one ( whatever the reason) they are said to use a :

[Pseudonym](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pseudonym) :

> - (noun). A fictitious name used when the person performs a particular social role. ( especially a pen name)

or [Alias:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/alias)

> - (noun) . An assumed name: The swindler worked under various aliases.
> - (adv).
>     Also known as; otherwise: Johnson, alias Johns.

- Luke was his  pseudonym/alias.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: That's the one.

Answer (score 0):

The question of rephrasing the sentence is not a question on Grammar, but on Semantics.

You can try to go dramatic which would be fitting for story-telling:

```
We call him Luke, but that's not his real name.
```

For a paragraph, or an essay:

```
His code name is Luke.
```

Dictionary reference: [code name](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/code%20name?s=t)

Comment: I agree with your first sentence, the grammar tag has been removed.